# How to access file on the webserver named Test%3f.htm

Tags: html, filenames, urlencode, url-encoding

I have a file named Test%3f.htm on my webserver.  I am trying to access the file through a web browser.  I realize the %3f decodes to a question mark which I do not want.  So I have tried to access it as  http://mysite.com/Test%253f.htm but have had no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you can't just rename the file?

Comment: No I cannot.  I have read other examples where people just encode the % to %25 and that solves the problem, but with this one it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth, I found that on IIS7, I was able to turn on

```
<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
```

in the web config.  This allowed the urls to be processed with the character in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

you need to  decode the the url this is encoded url the `%3f` is for `?`

[image]

Comment: The file just has the %3f within the real file name.  It is not there to intentionally be decoded.

Comment: you should not use the http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm in the name since browser will decode it